# Sequel Alternate solution for collectset

Tags: sql, oracle

QUERY Now

```
CREATE TABLE collect_char_wk1 STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT cluster, COLLECT_SET(characteristic)
FROM timeperiod1
GROUP BY cluster;
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
cluster  characteristic
 A        1
 A        2
 A        3
 B        2
 B        3
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
cluster  characteristic
 A        [1,2,3]
 B        [2,3]
```

currently this is working with the above query but , I want it to write in sql or plsql using similar functionality since we don't have collect_set in sql directly. 
Please let me know if there is any way to do it? Thank you

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Oracle 11g  version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Oracle aggregation techniques](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques):

What you are looking for is ***`LISTAGG`***. Here is how it could go in your case

```
select c1, LISTAGG(c2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)  from (
     select      'A' c1,         1 c2 from dual union all
     select      'A' c1,2 c2 from dual union all
     select      'A' c1,3 c2 from dual union all
     select      'B' c1,2 c2 from dual union all
     select      'B' c1,3 c2 from dual 
) group by c1 ;
```

(Notice it is a **pure `SQL`** solution)

Comment: Thank you chomel, Is there any precise way to write instead of this multiple select queries? for the larger dataset it would be difficult to write this query